# Syllables and word stressing

Tags: stress, syllables

I am an english learner but when it comes to syllables and streesing, a lot of words give me problems in pronoucing them.   When I was taught syllables and streesing they told me that every word has only one stressed syllable. Then when I made research on net ,I got to know that there are words with a secondary stress. But i failed to know any rule concerning words with two syllable stress.  So, is there any one with any clue or rule concerning words with secondary stress.                          A very simple example is a word like "enable". In my short thinking, I thought it had to be written like "eneible" in phonics spelling but checking in the dictionaries, it is written as "Ineible" appearing like the first and second vowels are stressed.

Comment: Why do you think that the notation "ineible" tells you anything about the stress? It is just noting the fact that many people pronounce the first "e" as [ɪ], as they do for many words with an **unstressed** 'e' in the first syllable. I don't know what the constraints are on secondary stress in English, but I'm sure that it only occurs in words of at least three syllables (I suspect, at least four) and it is never on an adjacent syllable to the primary stress.

Comment: Some dictionaries tell you which syllables have secondary stress. Compare [enable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/enable) /ɪˈneɪbl/, which only has one stress mark with [biological](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/biological) /ˌbaɪ.əˈlɒdʒ.ɪ.kəl/, which has primary stress on /ˈlɒdʒ/ and secondary stress on /ˌbaɪ/. Look at those little marks ˈ and ˌ for primary and secondary stress.